# XPath - Select Elements Not Containing Elements

Tags: html, xpath

I cant seem to find topic which answers this so I'm asking myself.
Since this is generic question for which answer can be applied to most documents, I think specific code example is not necessary.

Using XPath I want to select all table nodes which do not nest other tables.
So no other descendant table elements, and I also want to discard all tables which have spaces only as their value.

I have tried this:

```
//table[not(child::table) and normalize-space(.)]
```

but it's not working.

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are scraping (X)HTML, and noting that `table` cannot have another table as a direct child, it is likely that you are looking for `descendent` table elements, and not direct `child` elements.

```
table[not(descendant::table)]
```

In the Xml below:

```
<xml>
    <table id="hasDescendent">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="Inner Descendent"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="directChild">
        <table id="Inner Direct Child" />
    </table>
    <table id="nochild">
    </table>
</xml>
```

The xpath `//table[not(descendant::table)]` returns the following `table`s:

- Inner Descendent
- Inner Direct Child
- nochild

Comment: It's working. Yes, you are right. Descendant tables is what is being searched for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the following HTML fragment as an example:

```
<div>
    <table id="1">

    </table>

    <table id="2">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </table>

    <table id="3">
        <div>I'm the one you wanted to find</div>
    </table>
</div>
```

According to your description, the first `table` should be discarded since it contains only spaces, the second `table` should be discarded also, since there is another `table` inside.

The following xpath expression would match the third `table` only:

```
/div/table[(not(child::table) and normalize-space(.))]
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) tool):

```
$ xmllint index.html --xpath '/div/table[(not(child::table) and normalize-space(.))]'
<table id="3">
    <div>I'm the one you wanted to find</div>
</table>
```

Comment: StuartLC is right, I have formulated question wrong. Question should say "not containing descendant tables" not "child tables". Your solution works for empty tables though. Thanks.